# Ошибка getRunningServices is deprecated API 26

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-o

При написани данного кода:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> rs = am.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

`getRunningServices` зачеркнут, как прочитал начиная с ещё не вышедшего API Level 26(8.0 Android O) данный метод будет не доступен, как переделать так, чтобы в будущем работало и на API Level 26? 
Цель - это проверка запущен ли `Service`, при запуске приложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices

> As of O, this method is no longer available to third party
>   applications. For backwards compatibility, it will still return the
>   caller's own services.

Здесь сказано, что метод не будет доступен для *сторонних* приложений. А также сказано:

> Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing
>   service management type user interfaces.

То есть, рекомендуется использовать при отладке.

Простой совет дан здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/a/608600/6932590

Заведите в классе сервиса публичную статическую булеву переменную `isRunning` и меняйте ее при запуске сервиса (`onCreate/onStartCommand`) и при его остановке (`onDestroy`).

Comment: Если система убьёт процесс, то значение булевой переменной не будет верной.

Comment: При активном приложении на переднем плане Ваш сервис никто не убьет. Если Ваш сервис - единственный процесс и он будет уничтожен системой, то никакие значения статических полей не останутся существовать. На всякий случай, можете давать команду startService каждый раз при входе в приложение, а обрабатывать повторный вызов в onStartCommand.

Comment: Сейчас протестировал, запускается приложение в методе onCreate вызывается сервис, startService и через System.out.print вывожу начние startId. Затем я закрываю приложение (не скрываю именно закрытие).  Сервис закрывается без вызова метоад onDestroy и затем стартует заново аж 2 раза!  потому что startId возвращает значени = 3; Мне нужно реализовать сервис который потосянно будет слушать WebSocket и далее уведомлять пользователя мол  пришло сообщение

Comment: В таком случае Вам придется столкнуться большим количеством костылей и боли. Когда я разрабатывал мессенджер и решил держать постоянное XMPP соединение в сервисе, тоже очень хотелось чтобы он был бессмертен и пользователь не пропустил ни одного уведомления. Но тут сразу несколько ударов по яйцам: не хватка памяти - сервис сдох, энергосбережение включено - сервис сдох, ограничение фоновых процессов - сервис сдох (встречал на Xiaomi), ограничение фоновой интернет активности - сервис жив, но нет доступа в интернет. Если интересно как жить после этого - напишите в личку, поделюсь опытом.

Comment: @ДамирАрманов с удовольствием тоже бы послушал ваши советы...